# How to add external link to pdf using wicked_pdf?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf, wicked-gem

Let say for example I will put google.com link to some text in my pdf, and opens in new tab.

But this simple **a href tag** doesn't worked!

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Go to google</a>
```

The above code generates:

```
file://google.com/
```

How can I do that when I'm using **gem 'wicked_pdf'**

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `wicked_pdf`, but it looks like your google link is missing the http protocol.  You're going to want an absolute url like the following:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Go to google</a>
```

Try it out and see if that solves the problem

Comment: Hi @Ren, yes it works! Is it possible to use the target="_blank" to open the link in new tab?

Comment: Again i've never used wicked_pdf, but you can certainly try adding target='_blank' to the anchor tag and see if it works.

Comment: Also don't forget to accept my answer and upvote if it helped you :)

Comment: I tried to add target="_blank" but it goes automatically to the link, not opening a new tab.